# Saxon XSLT passing Parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, xslt, saxon

I'm having trouble setting parameters with Saxon 9.3. I have my basic transformation function

```
private void runXSLT(String inFile, String xslt, String outFile, String[] name, String[] val)
{
    Processor proc = new Processor();
    XdmNode input = proc.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(inFile));
    XsltTransformer transformer = proc.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xslt)).Load();
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;
    if (name != null)
      for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        transformer.SetParameter(new QName("", "", name[i]), new XdmAtomicValue(val[i]));
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    FileStream outStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    serializer.SetOutputStream(outStream);
    transformer.Run(serializer);
    outStream.Close();
}
```

where String[] name, and String[] val are arrays of equal length with parameter names and corresponding values. Example: name[0] is "version", val[0] is "1.0" and name[1] is "filename", val[1] is "test.xml"

I based this function off the sample code given in the documentation and it functions correctly for my various xslt transformations except when I have parameters to pass to the xslt. The transformation will occur as if the parameters were not set.

From debugging, I know that the program does run SetParameter for each value in my name array. I do have an xsl:param defined in each of my xslt documents and when using the command line tool *Transform.exe*, the parameters are input and I get the correct transformation.

Is there something wrong with how I'm trying to pass parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works from the command line, I can't see any obvious reason why it shouldn't work with this code. One difference is that the command line passes params as untypedAtomic, whereas you are passing them as strings - which could make a difference if version is expecting a number.

I would suggest following up on the saxon-help list (where messages are properly tracked - when you ask here, it's pure chance whether we happen to see the message) with a small reproducible sample giving all needed information - a full C# program, and a simple stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the suggestion to go smaller helped me test my function. I created a separate program specifically to run this function and figured out it does work which means there must be some obscure consistent error in how I was inputting the parameters to the function. If I have other problems I'll follow up with the saxon-help.